# pdf reader that mimics the user-experience of a physical book

Tags: pdf-viewer, ebooks, books

I'm using pdf versions of textbooks for college.

Digital Pdf readers are in many ways superior to reading a physical book (keyword searching, etc). However, there are certain things that you cannot easily do in adobe reader, that you can do very easily in a physical book:

- Hold one finger at page 23, and another at page 78, so that you can easily switch back and forth between them.
- Quickly put bookmarkers at different pages which you can see instantly, so that you can instantly go to a specific section on page 34 about a basic formula that is being used throughout the book. At the same time, hold your hand between the section you were working on to immediately switch back.
- Put [colored markers on sections you don't fully understand yet](http://minutes.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/post-it-study-pagemarkers.jpg), in order to instantly get back to them later.

I don't think that Adobe Reader allows you to do these things. You can go back to certain pages by going back to the premade contents bookmarks (if the pdf has them), but you can't easily switch back, without having to use your brain memory to remember page numbers.

**Is there a good way to mimic those advantages of physical books with a pdf reader?**